# RecyclerView item click is working on emulator but not on physical in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onitemclick

i have this function to setup the Recyclerview:

```
fun setUpRecyclerview() {
    clickToPatch()
    mAdapter.updateData(plannersList)
    recyclerView!!.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView?.adapter = mAdapter
    swipeToDelete()

}
```

and this is click to patch function:

```
fun clickToPatch() {
    recyclerView?.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
        var downTouch = false
        override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            when (e.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> downTouch = true
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> if (downTouch) {
                    downTouch = false
                    recyclerView!!.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)?.let {
                        val position = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(it)
                        val id: Int = mAdapter.plannersList?.get(position)!!.id
                        showPatchIbadahDialog(id)
                    }
                }
                else -> downTouch = false
            }
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(rv, e)
        }
    })

}
```

so when i click the item in emulator i it work fine and i can patch the item but when i try to click the item on physical phone, nothing happen and clicking on the item isn't responsive

what am i doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

onBindViewHolder:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemBaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(plannersList?.get(position)!!)

}
```

Comment: You want to set  a single `clickListener` on the whole `recyclerView`?

Comment: Shift "downTouch = false" below "showPatchIbadahDialog(id)".

Comment: @Praveen i want to set clicklistener for each item of the recyclerview not clicklistenr for the whole recyclerview

Comment: @AtulYadav nothing changed

Comment: @Enigma Then why aren't you setting `clickListeners` for each item inside `onBindViewHolder`??

Comment: @Praveen i have updated my question and included onBindViewHolder from adapter, do i need to add anything to it?

Comment: @Enigma Yeah, you can directly set `clickListeners` for each item, inside your `bind` method. Should I post an answer?

Comment: @Praveen yes please, that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `clickListeners` for each items of your `recyclerView` inside `bind` method of your `viewHolder` class.

```
class PlannerListhHolder(private val plannerListBinding: PlannerItemBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(plannerListBinding.root) {
            fun bind(plannerItem: PlannerItem) {
                plannerListBinding.root.setOnClickListener {
                    //show your dialog
                }
            }
        }
```